# Parsing JSON from URL

Tags: java, json, url

Is there any simplest way to parse JSON from a URL? I used Gson I can't find any helpful examples.

Comment: for example it will be like this http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SIFL9qfmu5U?alt=json
or from facebook graph

Answer (score 70, accepted):

1. **First you need to download the URL (as text):**

   ```
   private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
       BufferedReader reader = null;
       try {
           URL url = new URL(urlString);
           reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
           StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
           int read;
           char[] chars = new char[1024];
           while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
               buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 

           return buffer.toString();
       } finally {
           if (reader != null)
               reader.close();
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Then you need to parse it (and here you have some options).**

   - **GSON (full example):**

     ```
     static class Item {
         String title;
         String link;
         String description;
     }

     static class Page {
         String title;
         String link;
         String description;
         String language;
         List<Item> items;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         String json = readUrl("http://www.javascriptkit.com/"
                               + "dhtmltutors/javascriptkit.json");

         Gson gson = new Gson();        
         Page page = gson.fromJson(json, Page.class);

         System.out.println(page.title);
         for (Item item : page.items)
             System.out.println("    " + item.title);
     }
     ```

     Outputs:

     ```
     javascriptkit.com
         Document Text Resizer
         JavaScript Reference- Keyboard/ Mouse Buttons Events
         Dynamically loading an external JavaScript or CSS file
     ```
   - **Try the java API from [json.org](http://json.org/java):**

     ```
     try {
         JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl("..."));

         String title = (String) json.get("title");
         ...

     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     ```

Comment: 'java' tag indicates that he doesn't want to use javascript.

Comment: @Salah Yahya: Added GSON example + how to download an url

Comment: This will MANGLE the JSON and produce parsing-errors. Its completely unnecessary to build your own string from the received contents of a URL, GSON supports reading from BufferedReader directly. THIS EXAMPLE WILL NOT WORK IN EVERY CASE

Comment: can you use generics to load an arbitrary JSON?

Comment: Needs to be updated. Link is broken and it's unclear what should replace the final "..."

Answer (score 15):

[GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) has a builder that takes a [Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) object: **[`fromJson(Reader json, Class<T> classOfT)`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Class-)**.

This means you can create a Reader from a URL and then pass it to Gson to consume the stream and do the deserialisation.

Only **three lines** of relevant code.

```java
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonFetchNetworkJson {

    public static void main(String[] ignored) throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("https://httpbin.org/get?color=red&shape=oval");
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
        MyDto dto = new Gson().fromJson(reader, MyDto.class);

        // using the deserialized object
        System.out.println(dto.headers);
        System.out.println(dto.args);
        System.out.println(dto.origin);
        System.out.println(dto.url);
    }
    
    private class MyDto {
        Map<String, String> headers;
        Map<String, String> args;
        String origin;
        String url;
    }
}
```

> <sup>If you happen to get a 403 error code with an endpoint which otherwise works fine (e.g. with `curl` or other clients) then a possible cause could be that the endpoint expects a `User-Agent` header and by default Java URLConnection is not setting it. An easy fix is to add at the top of the file e.g. `System.setProperty("http.agent", "Netscape 1.0");`.</sup>

##### Maven dependency

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
```

##### Gradle dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
```

Comment: what if the json - args having the array elements ?

Comment: @Sundar: for arrays you'd use TypeToken: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10292824/191246

Answer (score 10):

You could use org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils for downloading and org.json.JSONTokener for parsing:

```
JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SIFL9qfmu5U?alt=json"))).nextValue();
System.out.println(jo.getString("version"));
```

Comment: I think you have to add `.openStream()` after `new URL(...)`. So it has to look like this:
`JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/SIFL9qfmu5U?alt=json").openStream())).nextValue();`

Comment: @ Selphiron, Working perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a easy method.

First parse the JSON from url -

```
public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);

    try {

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == 200) {

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }

            inputStream.close();

        } else {
            Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Then place a task and then read the desired value from JSON -

```
private class ReadPlacesFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        JSONObject json;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(result);

        ////CREATE A JSON OBJECT////

        JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("JSON OBJECT NAME");

        ////GET A STRING////

        String title = data.getString("");

        //Similarly you can get other types of data
        //Replace String to the desired data type like int or boolean etc.

        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }

        //GETTINGS DATA FROM JSON ARRAY//

        try {

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray postalCodesItems = new JSONArray(
                    jsonObject.getString("postalCodes"));

                JSONObject postalCodesItem = postalCodesItems
                        .getJSONObject(1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ReadPlacesFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

You can then place a task like this -

```
new ReadPlacesFeedTask()
    .execute("JSON URL");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static TargetClassJson downloadPaletteJson(String url) throws IOException {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(url)) {
            return null;
        }
        String genreJson = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url).openStream());
        return new Gson().fromJson(genreJson, TargetClassJson.class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.URIUtil;
 import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
 import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
 import java.io.File;

    tmpDir = "/defineYourTmpDir"
    URL url = new URL("http://yourOwnURL.com/file.json");
    String path = tmpDir + "/tmpRemoteJson" + ".json";
    remoteJsonFile = new File(path);
    remoteJsonFile.deleteOnExit(); 
    FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, remoteJsonFile);
    String fileTMPPath = remoteJsonFile.getPath();

    def inputTMPFile = new File(fileTMPPath);
    remoteParsedJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputTMPFile.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use java 1.8
with com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Integer      value = mapper.readValue(new URL("your url here"), Integer.class);
```

Integer.class can be also a complex type. Just for example used.

Answer (score -7):

A simple alternative solution:

- Paste the URL into a json to csv converter
- Open the CSV file in either Excel or Open Office
- Use the spreadsheet tools to parse the data

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. I don't think that using Excel is a complex solution to this problem.

Comment: promoting a json to csv converter maybe?