# How to deserialize a JSON array of objects using Gson library?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am facing an issue while I am trying to deserialize a JSON array of objects using the Gson library.

An example of the JSON array:

```
[
    {"ID":1,"Title":"Lion","Description":"bla bla","ImageURL":"http:\/\/localhost\/lion.jpg"},
    {"ID":1,"Title":"Tiger","Description":"bla bla","ImageURL":"http:\/\/localhost\/tiger.jpg"}
]
```

What do you think? What is the proper Java code to deserialize such a JSON response?

Comment: Is there more direction you can provide about the problem?  What is the input, where are you getting it from, what are you trying?

Comment: The Proplem is when I try to get a Objcet[] array usin gson.fromJson() I get a null vule , I get this JSON array from a PHP page :

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To deserialize a JSONArray you need to use TypeToken. You can read more about it from [GSON user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). Example code:

```
@Test
public void JSON() {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>(){}.getType();
    // In this test code i just shove the JSON here as string.
    List<Asd> asd = gson.fromJson("[{'name':\"test1\"}, {'name':\"test2\"}]", listType);
}
```

If you have a JSONArray then you can use

```
...
JSONArray jsonArray = ...
gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), listType);
...
```

Comment: what is List<Asd> asd here?

Comment: Can anyone help me with this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666558/deserializing-json-array-using-gson ?

Comment: FYI, for Type is java.lang.reflect.Type. There're million Type classes so auto complete might be confusing.

Comment: If the JsonArray is of a known type the best way might be 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133484/deserializing-a-jsonarray-of-doubles

Comment: THis doesn't seem to work. "Asd" is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

For example your service has such response

[ new SomeObject(), new SomeObject(), new SomeObject() ] - this is jsonArray

SomeObject - is a class instance of that your array is contains.

You should use special class TypeToken (docs here https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<SomeObject>>(){}.getType();



String jsonArray = restResponse.getPayload(); - you get response as String
List<SomeObject > list = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, type);
```

Done!