# Spring MVC - Deserialize JSON array

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, spring-mvc

I'm trying to pass data to my controller using Ajax and JSON.

I've got an HTML table and I've got to send multiple coordinates of that table to my controller. So I made a Javascript array containing anonymous objects of this kind :

```
{ 
    DAY: someIndex, 
    HOUR: someOtherIndex 
}
```

and let this array be called `coordinates`, I serialized it like this:

```
JSON.stringify(coordinates)
```

so then in an ajax call (`type: POST`) I used `data: JSON.stringify(coordinates)`.

In my document ready I used :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers : {
        Accept : "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
});
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
String update(@PathVariable int id, @RequestBody String coordinates, HttpServletResponse response) {

    // Do something here to convert it in my complex structure

}
```

However  I don't know what the type should be for the parameter `coordinates`.

I'm using `GSON`. And I wasn't able to deserialize it easily. I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10292824/505810) solution, but it wouldn't work. (Kept asking to cast types for some reason.)

Since I didn't think it'd be possible to deserialize this correctly, I tried to serialize the coordinates as another format (just a JSON array of strings where the coordinates are split by a token (`;) here`

So my array the javascript objects are created like this in a `foreach`:

```
coordinates.push( someIndex.toString() + ";" + someOtherIndex.toString() );
```

And I kept the stringify part.

So now when I `POST` the data to my controller, I output the value with `System.out.println(coordinates)` and the output looks weird.

```
%5B%220%3B8%22%5D=
```

for this object in the Javascript console : `["0;8"]`.

So my questions :

1. Is this a good approach?
2. Is it possible to deserialize a JSON array into some java types? Such as `List<Coordinate>` ? ( I've tried using this type instead of `String` in my controller, but it would give me an error `415 - Unsupported media type`)
3. If I'm using the String approach, is there a way to translate that gibberish into something I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `%5B%220%3B8%22%5D=` on server side, cause jQuery by default serializes data to query string.

You need to set the content type of the request to `application/json` using `contentType` jQuery option.

Then you'll probably want to take a look at some implementation of GsonHttpMessageConverter for simpler RequestBody conversion. Here is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019162/custom-httpmessageconverter-with-responsebody-to-do-json-things) and it looks like there's one in [spring for android](http://static.springsource.org/spring-android/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/GsonHttpMessageConverter.html) so maybe you can use that.

Comment: Indeed, the contentType did it! thanks. I'll keep the question opened, in case someone answers my other questions. +1.

Comment: @Pacane well, your question number 1 solicits opinion, for 2 you need the converter mentioned above and no 3 just got solved by setting content type ;)