# How to process an associative array from JSON in Android Java

Tags: java, android, json, associative-array

I am trying to process the JSON output from https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest in my Android app, which is returned in this format:

```
{
  "rates": {
    "CAD": 1.5613,
    "HKD": 8.9041,
    ...
    "KRW": 1374.71,
    "MYR": 4.8304
  },
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2020-03-09"
}
```

I would like to use GSON to process this JSON, so I have added a class ExchangeRates to recieve the data:

```
class ExchangeRates {
    private String base;
    private String date;
}
```

These commands load the JSON into my ExchangeRates class:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ExchangeRates mExchangeRates = gson.fromJson(result, ExchangeRates.class);
```

However, I cannot figure out how to load the associative array of exchange rates into the class in a scalable manner.  I know I could add a static list of the currencies, but I want the code to be able to automatically handle additional currencies if they are added at a later date.

Comment: Have you though about a custom deserializer?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27666558/deserializing-json-array-using-gson) is a similar solution on StackOverflow.

Comment: Could'nt you use a HashMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be very simple, and yes, @ya379, a HashMap was part of the answer.  Given a HashMap data type, GSON will translate the associative array part of the JSON directly to a HashMap:

```
class ExchangeRates {
    private String base;
    private String date;
    private HashMap<String, Double> rates;
}
```