# Parse JSON string from remote URL in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing, mobile, json-rpc

Well I'm new to Android. I'm getting a JSON string from a remote URL.

```
[{"key":"myString1","val":"myValue1"},{"key":"myString2","val":"myValue2"},{"key":"myString3","val":"myValue3"},{"key":"myString4","val":"myValue4"},{"key":"myString5","val":"myValue5"}]
```

I just need to parse this JSON string & display all key-val pair. I tried something like below from one of the tutorial.

```
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);

        json = jArray.getJSONObject(0); //This will take first pair.
```

But I don't know the syntax for iterating through whole json object. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON from URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467568/parsing-json-from-url)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special in it. You do it like iterating any other array.
Let's say you have two String arrays to be filled with values: `String[] mKey, mValue`

Reading from JSON array will be like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
    mKey[i] = object.getString("key");
    mValue[i] = object.getString("val");
}
```

Comment: How to assign assign those value to TextView defined already? Can I assign values within loop to TextView ? Sorry, I'm newbie in Android Programming.

Comment: myTextView.setText(); better set TetView text outside the loop. You can use StringBuilder to generate a string with key-value pairs, then set TextView text.