# Trying to download URL contetnt into .txt file using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to download the content of pages like [this one](http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/locations?query=Aarau)
and writing it into a .txt file for later use.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
String cityInfo = doc.html();            

int index = cityInfo.indexOf("},"); // keeps just the first object as it has the highest score.
String cityInfo1 = cityInfo.substring(index+1) + "}]}"; // gets the object in the correct format as some characters are not selected when downloading
bw1.write(cityInfo1); //saves json object into text file
```

I keep getting this error, and if I use the `ignoreContentType(true)` method it just gets rid of the error and my text file remains empty.

```
"Exception in thread "main" 
org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. 
Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml.
Mimetype=application/json, URL=http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/locations?query=Aarau"
```

Comment: Why use Jsoup for Json formatted data ?

Comment: I want to download the whole page only as text and handle it later. What would you suggest?

Comment: Check out the JSON Format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467568/parsing-json-from-url

Comment: I didn't get if the first part reads the page's URL or the page's content

Comment: It reads the content. Then, in the second part, the content is parsed and can be used.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked fine! Should I delete my question now? since there is not an answer to that..

Comment: You might as well leave it, it might be helpful to someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `ignoreContentType(true)`:

`doc = Jsoup.connect(link).ignoreContentType(true).userAgent("Mozilla").get();`

Comment: I tried but still nothing gets written in my text file. I get this instead: "Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=405, URL=http://transport.opendata.ch/v1/locations?query=Aarau"

Comment: Ah, then that's the inverse - the 405 is indicating that the server doesn't understand what you are supplying or isn't willing to return a type that it thinks you are asking for.  The solution is to be more specific about the content type you supply and request.

Comment: So should I download it as just text, JSON or another format type?