# Saving data from url to JSON object

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have to create JSON parser to save data received from url into JSON object using org.json library and only java standard libraries but I have no idea how to connec to those

```
 String line = "326";

    URL oracle = new URL("https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/"+line+"/Arrivals?app_id=&app_key=");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

This my connection code

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a JSON parser such as Jackson.

1. Create a class that would store the data you want to store from
   that JSON.
2. Use URL to connect and grab the JSON
3. Use Jackson to convert it to a Java object

Let me know if you need more help and I can provide it.

Comment: Can you specify how to grab this JSON?
It's my first attempt with URL and JSON format and

Comment: Check my answer on how to make http call and parse the incoming string body

Comment: There are multiple other stackoverflow answers that can show you how to pull it step by step. Ill link a few here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467568/parsing-json-from-url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308554/simplest-way-to-read-json-from-a-url-in-java

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting some progress although now I'm getting error:

Comment: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
null at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:432)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:184)
 at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:310)
 at GetData.WasteOfTime.main(WasteOfTime.java:31)

Comment: I know that its to do with the first symbol on the website I read data from not being {, but is there any way to ignore first symbol while using BufferedReader

Answer (score 0):

Use an http client library like [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) to make the request and get the string body.

Then use a json parser like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to parse the received string into Json object.

Use okhttp as below:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url(url)
  .build();

Response resp = client.newCall(request).execute();
String response =  resp.body().string();
```

Once you have the response string you can make a jsonNode from it by using Jackson ObjectMapper as below

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(response);
```

Or get your defined POJO by parsing the response as

```
YourClass mappedPOJO = mapper.readValue(response, YourClass.class);
```

Lets say your incoming json was

```
{
    "key1":"value1",
    "key2": {
        "key3":"value3"
    }
}
```

Then `tree.get("key1")` gives you "value1",

`tree.get("key1").get("key2")` gives you "value3"

Comment: I can only use java standard libraries and org.jason one