# NullPointerException in AsyncTask while getting JSON file from URL

Tags: android, json, listview, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have a JSON file and uploaded it on my server, then I fetch it in my android app. But every time i try to debug my app, it crashes with **Null Pointer Exception** in the AsyncTask class and gives me this error:

```
10-30 05:07:46.268 8710-9073/com.example.prof_mohamedatef.listview E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.example.prof_mohamedatef.listview.androidlistviewactivity$FetchUsersDesires.doInBackground(androidlistviewactivity.java:159)
  at com.example.prof_mohamedatef.listview.androidlistviewactivity$FetchUsersDesires.doInBackground(androidlistviewactivity.java:84)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I am assured that my devices is connected to the internet. I adopt in **url** which may be built wrongly, it may requires question mark **?** or any other **symbols**, or my json file may be hasn't constructed correctly. Please review my url : https://yourbest-online.com/images/xml_files/Desires.json and my json code:

```
{"page":1,"Desires": [{
        "hotels": {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "hotels booking",
            "thumb_url": "https://yourbest-online.com/images/xml_files/hotels.png"
        },
        "Aviation": {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Aviation Tickets Booking",
            "thumb_url": "https://yourbest-online.com/images/xml_files/aviation.png"
        }
],"total_results":2,"total_pages":1}
```

This is all of my AsyncTask Class including doInBackground method where the problem always occur :

```
    public class FetchUsersDesires extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<OptionsEntity>> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchUsersDesires.class.getSimpleName();

    private ArrayList<OptionsEntity> getUsersDesiresFromJson(String UsersDesires)
            throws JSONException {

        UsersDesiresJson = new JSONObject(UsersDesires);
        UsersDesiresJsonAray = UsersDesiresJson.getJSONArray(main_List);

        list.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < UsersDesiresJsonAray.length(); i++) {

            // Get the JSON object representing a movie per each loop
            oneOptionData = UsersDesiresJsonAray.getJSONObject(i);

            ID_STRING = oneOptionData .getString(ID);
            TITLE_STRING = oneOptionData .getString(TITLE);
            Image_URL_STRING = oneOptionData .getString(Image_URL);

            mAdapter=null;
            OptionsEntity entity = new OptionsEntity(Image_URL_STRING, TITLE_STRING);
            list.add(entity);
        }

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<OptionsEntity> doInBackground(String... params) {

        String UsersDesires_JsonSTR = null;

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                UsersDesires_JsonSTR = null;
            }

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            UsersDesires_JsonSTR = buffer.toString();

            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Users Desires String: " + UsersDesires_JsonSTR);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error here Exactly ", e);

            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            return getUsersDesiresFromJson(UsersDesires_JsonSTR);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "didn't got Users Desires from getJsonData method", e);

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<OptionsEntity> result) {
        if (result != null&& getApplicationContext()!=null) {
            mAdapter = new LazyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_row, result);
            listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** , Connection now is running on the best way, but **JSON Exception** appear says : "**No Value for id**" and the json String variable value in android studio looks like that : **"{"page":1,"Desires": [{
        "hotels": {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "hotels booking",
            "thumb_url": "https://yourbest-online.com/images/xml_files/hotels.png"
        },
        "Aviation": {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "Aviation Tickets Booking",
            "thumb_url": "https://yourbest-online.com/images/xml_files/aviation.png"
        }
}],"total_results":2,"total_pages":1}
"**
the value looks like to include multiple \n\t\t\t symbols for each space, i think this my causing the problem, any advise for this purpose please.

your help will be appreciated. thank you

Comment: Are you getting the null pointer exception because you are not getting any data from the url? or the reason is different!!

Comment: what does the Null Pointer Exception say?

Comment: @ginomempin review edit for Null Pointer exception

Comment: @WasiAhmad yes the null pointer exception reason is that there are no data coming via url

Comment: Since your url is working fine, there should not be any problem. Can you check the first answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467568/parsing-json-from-url to read the url as text? then try to parse the json object.

Comment: I think your json is invalid, it's missing a closing `}` before the closing `]` (to match the opening `{` in `"Desires": [{`. I don't know what's at "androidlistviewactivity.java:159" that's throwing the NPE, but it could be that your parsed JSON is null.

Comment: It's nice that you gave the logcat, but we have to see a [mcve] in order to help you. We can't see your code at all.

Comment: And, no, your JSON [is not valid](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @ginomempin you can review my AsyncTask Class and doInbackground method again after my recent edit

Comment: @cricket_007 you can review my AsyncTask Class and doInbackground method again after my recent edi

Comment: You didn't edit your JSON.. Did you? It's still invalid. Here's a suggestion: Use Retrofit with the Gson converter or OkHttp, or Volley, to do your network requests. There's not much reason to use HttpURLConnection in my opinion. Especially if you are having lots of JSON files to deal with

Comment: can you mark lines 159 and 84 in `androidlistviewactivity.java` (edit the question and put some mark next to the lines

Comment: @cricket_007 after editing json file, it successfully connected, but gave me JSON Exception "No value for id" at the hotels node. please, Review my post edit at this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the value of `oneOptionData` here. It doesn't have an ID key. It has either hotels or aviation.

```
ID_STRING = oneOptionData .getString(ID) ;
```

So, that's going to crash with a JSON parsing exception. Your parsing exception causes you to return null.

You should never return a null list from an AsyncTask meant to return a list of data. You should instead return an empty list, and appropriately log the parsing error  if/when it occurs

Get a better json format.

```
 "Desires": [{
        "id": "1",
        "category":"hotels",
        "title": "hotels booking",
        "thumb_url": "https://yourbest-online.com/images/xml_files/hotels.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "category":" Aviation", 
        "title": "Aviation Tickets Booking",
        "thumb_url": "https://yourbest-online.com/images/xml_files/aviation.png"
    }
```

Aside: a JSON file is in a directory called `xml_files`? And there is a directory called `xml_files` under `images`? If this is your server, I'd suggest also reorganization of your overall code, and instead use an actual REST API to generate your JSON instead of hosting plain text files